# How can I tell if I have successfully imported a package for python (e.g. Pandas) in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VS code, I am trying to do a project using Jupyter notebook on VS code. I tried typing [import pandas as pd] after installing pandas using pip. I pressed the run button and nothing visible changed except the bracket for the cell turning to 1. [-] -> [1]

How can I know if this import was successful?

Edit: Ok I understand how to tell now, Thank You everyone!

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
import pandas as pd
```

if it runs without `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you do not have to worry much about this issue, no output means you have imported a module successfully or it will give some err like `ModuleNotFoundError`.

If you want to confirm this, there are 2 ways I can provide:

1. just try to use this module, for example

```py
pd.__version__
```

if it gives a version number and doesn't report any err, you success.

2. execute

```py
import sys
sys.module.keys()
```

and if `pandas` is in the output list, it has been imported.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an example to test if it works, try this

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
print(dates)
```